# How to set the expiration for the Google Analytics _gat cookie to 0 to make it a session only cookie?

Tags: google-analytics

It is my understanding that analytics.js sets two cookies _ga and _gat.  _ga can be set to 0 using ga create function and setting 'cookieExpires': 0.  Can you set _gat expiration to 0 as well to make it a session cookie?  If so how do you do that?

Comment: Where did you hear/read about the _gac cookie? I am no familiar with that.

Comment: It is referenced in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

It is the only other persistent cookie used by the analytics.js as far as I know.  If you check a site you can see that it is definitely being set with a 10 minute expiration.